# Не срабатывает одна из команд в aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой: не срабатывает одна команда(new_book), хотя все остальные работают, кто в курсе в чем может быть причина?

Команды

```
async def set_default_commands(dp):
    await dp.bot.set_my_commands([
        types.BotCommand("start", "Запустить бота "),
        types.BotCommand("help", "Помощь "),
        types.BotCommand("find_book", "Поиск книги по автору или названию "),
        types.BotCommand("new_book", "Поиск новых книг")
    ])
```

К примеру команда find_book отрабатывает без проблем, код там идентичный:

find_book

```
@dp.message_handler(Command("find_book"))
async def choose_book(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Введите автора или название книги')
    await FindBook.book.set()
```

new_book

```
@dp.message_handler(Command("new_book"))
async def looking_new_book(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Приступаю к поиску новых книг')
    await FindNewBook.book.set()
```

start

```
@dp.message_handler(CommandStart())
async def bot_start(message: types.Message):
    text = 'Приветствую!  \nЧтобы узнать функционал бота, пропишите комманду /help'
    await message.answer(text)
```

help

```
@dp.message_handler(CommandHelp())
async def bot_help(message: types.Message):
    text = [
        'Список комманд',
        '/start - запустить бота',
        '/help - получить справку',
        '/find_book - поиск книги по названию',
        '/new_book - поиск новых книг'
    ]

    await message.answer('\n'.join(text))
```

Comment: А пришли весь код. Может быть проблема в порядке хендлеров. О, есть ещё вариант, что ты сначала вводишь первую команду, потом в ней запускается fsm, а потом ты ввел вторую но так как уже запущен стейт, то проверка `@dp.message_handler(Command("new_book"), state=None)` не проходит так как стейт уже не None.

Comment: Дополнил код. Меня заинтересовало твое предположение по поводу проблемы в порядке хендлеров, можешь пожалуйста объяснить этот момент поподробнее? Я не понял его. Насчет фсм наврятли, так как я вначале запускаю команду, без стейтов, стейты появляются уже потом. Я могу использовать другие команды, потом запустить /new_book, ничего не произойдет, после этого дальше использовать остальные команды, они запустятся

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге проверил у себя твой код, но урезал до минимума.

```
from aiogram import executor, types
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Command
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State

from loader import dp


class FindBook(StatesGroup):
    book = State()


class FindNewBook(StatesGroup):
    book = State()


@dp.message_handler(Command("find_book"))
async def choose_book(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Введите автора или название книги')
    await FindBook.book.set()


@dp.message_handler(Command("new_book"))
async def looking_new_book(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Приступаю к поиску новых книг')
    await FindNewBook.book.set()


@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(message.text)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Он тоже после ввода new_book или find_book перестал реагировать на другие команды. Причина та о которой я писал в комментарии - запускается машина состояний и проверка в хендлере не проходит.
Исправить эту ситуацию можно двумя способами, в зависимости от того что вам нужно.

Первый это сделать хендлер с `state="*", Command('cancel')`, которая будет сбрасывать ЛЮБОЙ стейт `state.finish() #внутри функции` и потом команды будут снова работать.

Второй похож на первый, но только вместо того чтобы создавать новый хендлер ты добавишь к остальным хендлерам тот самый `state="*"` и тогда они будут срабатывать.

Comment: Извиняюсь за беспокойство, все оказалось гораздо проще, я в файле init не указал эти файлы(для каждой команды создавал отдельные файлы), поэтому он не реагировал